# The something difference between FlashBuilder 4.0 and FlashCS5?

Tags: actionscript-3

I use stage's getObjectsUnderPoint's method to get something.

when click a button, I will get the button's internal state's displayObject, and when iterate it's parent property I encounter a very strange problem

this button has four state(the Shape DisplayObject), In Flash IDE, I trace the state's parent, it output the SimpleButton, It's right!!, but in flashBuilder, output "null"..but it's stage's property is not null.. who know the reason?

my FlashIDE's version is FlashCS5, and FlashBuilder's sdk is 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason, read the Adobe's SimpleButton document

Starting with Player version 11.2 / AIR version 3.2, the parent property of the states of a SimpleButton object will report null if queried.